# Calling a WCF DataService [WebGet] function from the client

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, stored-procedures, odata

I have an EF4 model with a stored procedure that I want to call from the client.
The server code looks like this:

```
[WebGet]        
public IQueryable<SalesData> GetSalesReport(int reportType, int yr, int m, int d)
{
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(yr, m, d);
    return this.CurrentDataSource.RP_SalesReport(reportType, dt, dt).AsQueryable<SalesData>();
}
```

When calling this using IE using the URL "http://localhost:12345/MyService.svc/GetSalesReport?reportType=1&yr=2009&m=4&d=2" it works as expected.

In my client application I added a reference to the Service (http://localhost:12345/MyService.svc) and whetever I have tried, the function "GetSalesReport" does not show up in the object browser.
(Normal EF entities does show up in the object browser)

So my question is: How do I call this function from the Client ?

And is there a difference on how to call this function depending on the client (I want to call this function from a Windows Phone 7 Silverlight App, but right now I am testing using a WPF test client).

Comment: What attributes do you have associated with this method in the ServiceContract?

Comment: This is a ADO.NET Data Service (code name "Astoria") and the only attribute I have is the [WebGet]. As far as I know, you can't add a [ServiceContract] on a ADO.NET Data Service.

Comment: Did you check generated code? You should have a huge file with generated entities. Does it have an entry for GetSalesReport and how does it look?

Comment: When looking at the metdadata in IE, using the URL "http://localhost:12345/GoldService.svc/$metadata" the function shows up.

Comment: MetaData:
<FunctionImport Name="GetSalesReport" EntitySet="SalesDatas" ReturnType="Collection(MyModel.SalesData)" m:HttpMethod="GET">
  <Parameter Name="reportType" Type="Edm.Int32" Mode="In" /> 
  <Parameter Name="yr" Type="Edm.Int32" Mode="In" /> 
  <Parameter Name="m" Type="Edm.Int32" Mode="In" /> 
  <Parameter Name="d" Type="Edm.Int32" Mode="In" /> 
</FunctionImport>

Comment: According to an old post (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/776e2347-1575-49dc-ac34-531211cf68a5) Microsoft doesnt code gen ServiceOps as method calls, and you have to hand code the call. Is this still true ?

Comment: I see. Then this is probably the case. But can't you expose it through the model instead of manually adding WebGet?

Answer (score 4):

Actually it looks like the ADO.NET DataTeam hasn't implemented CodeGen for calling a ServiceMethod from the client.

So the soloution to my problem is to write this code at the client:

```
        // execute the service operation
        Uri u = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/GetSalesReport?reportType={1}&yr={2}&m={3}&d={4}", 
                      context.BaseUri, 1, 2009, 4, 2),UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

        var datas = context.Execute<SalesData>(u);
```

Thanks to Gil Fink that wrote this Blog post: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/11/14/consuming-data-services-service-operations.aspx

Comment: This scenario can lead to other problem: currently OData-generated proxies do not support complex types, only entity types. That means that in case SalesData is defined as a complex type ("ComplexType" element in CSDL), the OData-generated response will not be formatted as a feed. The workaround is to define complex type as entity, something that may require defining fake tables.